# Including gaps when merging data frames with rbind

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I am merging several `data.frame`s with `rbind` in R. I would like the output to include a break between each `data.frame` such as a new line with only the '#' character between `data.frame`s.

Please let me know if/how this is possible.

Comment: The whole point of `rbind`ing is to make it one continuous block of data. If you want to keep things separate, you are better of collecting all the data.frames in a `list`

Comment: What is your aim here? I think we could help you if you provided us with more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Since you're talking about "output," are you primarily interested in how your data look when printed or formatted for some document?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure *why* someone would want to do this except for visual separation. If that's the case, perhaps you can use a function something like this (but note that the output isn't really functional).

```
hashbind <- function(..., hash = "#") {
  lst <- list(...)
  Nchar <- max(rapply(lst, function(y) nchar(as.character(y)))) + 2
  do.call(
    rbind, 
    lapply(lst, function(x) {
      rbind(x, substr(paste(rep(hash, Nchar), collapse = ""), 1, Nchar))
    }))
}
```

Let's try it out with some `data.frame`s:

```
d1 <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4)
d2 <- data.frame(A = 5:6, B = 7:8)
d3 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20)

hashbind(d1, d2, d3)
#       A    B
# 1     1    3
# 2     2    4
# 3  #### ####
# 4     5    7
# 5     6    8
# 6  #### ####
# 7     1   11
# 8     2   12
# 9     3   13
# 10    4   14
# 11    5   15
# 12    6   16
# 13    7   17
# 14    8   18
# 15    9   19
# 16   10   20
# 17 #### ####
```

And some matrices:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
m2 <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)
m3 <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 2)

hashbind(m1, m2, m3)
#       [,1]   [,2]  
#  [1,] "1"    "3"   
#  [2,] "2"    "4"   
#  [3,] "####" "####"
#  [4,] "5"    "7"   
#  [5,] "6"    "8"   
#  [6,] "####" "####"
#  [7,] "1"    "11"  
#  [8,] "2"    "12"  
#  [9,] "3"    "13"  
# [10,] "4"    "14"  
# [11,] "5"    "15"  
# [12,] "6"    "16"  
# [13,] "7"    "17"  
# [14,] "8"    "18"  
# [15,] "9"    "19"  
# [16,] "10"   "20"  
# [17,] "####" "####"
```

The visual separator can be custom defined:

```
hashbind(d1, d2, d3, hash = "-")
#       A    B
# 1     1    3
# 2     2    4
# 3  ---- ----
# 4     5    7
# 5     6    8
# 6  ---- ----
# 7     1   11
# 8     2   12
# 9     3   13
# 10    4   14
# 11    5   15
# 12    6   16
# 13    7   17
# 14    8   18
# 15    9   19
# 16   10   20
# 17 ---- ----
```

---

Of course, a similar (but not identical) approach can be achieved by just using the `by` print method. For instance, check out the output for:

```
print.by(list(m1, d2, d3))
```